# How to capture multiple occurences of subpattern into one capture?

Tags: php, regex

I want a regex expression which will capture multiple occurrences into one group. As an example, imagine the following phrases:

```
cat | likes her | mat
dog | goes to his | basket
```

I want to be able to capture each part of the phrase into a fixed position

```
array(
  0 => cat likes her mat
  1 => cat
  2 => likes her
  3 => mat
)
```

Obviously using:

```
$regex = '/(cat|dog)( likes| goes| to| his| her)* (mat|basket)/';
preg_match($regex, "The cat likes her mat", $m);
```

gives:

```
array(
  0 => cat likes her mat
  1 => cat
  2 =>  likes
  3 =>  her
  4 => mat
)
```

But I always want mat/basket in $m[3], regardless of how many words are matched in the middle.

I have tried this:

```
$regex = '/(cat|dog)(?:( likes| goes| to| his| her)*) (mat|basket)/';
```

to try and prevent capturing of the multiple subpatterns, but this causes only the first word to be captured i.e.

```
array(
  0 => cat likes her mat
  1 => cat
  2 =>  likes
  3 => mat
)
```

Does anyone know how I can capture the whole of the middle part of the phrase (of an unknown number of wards length), but still get it into predicted output.

btw I cannot use `(cat|dog).*?(mat|basket)` because there are only specified words which are allowed in the middle.

The above is just an example; the actual usage has many more options for each of the subpatterns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

did you try this pattern:

```
/\b(cat|dog) ((?: ?(?:likes|goes|to|his|her)\b)*) ?(mat|basket)\b/
```

Comment: Thank you. In my actual usage, all the 'words' are fixed length and always separated by a space. So this pattern does just what I need.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: you could also try to solve the empty middle words problem to accept `cat mat`.

Comment: First time I have posted a query on this site. Brilliant answers in less than hour. Very grateful to all.

Answer (score 1):

How about this pattern?

```
$regex = '/\b(cat|dog)\b((?:\b(?:\s+|likes|goes|to|his|her)\b)*)\b(mat|basket)\b/';
preg_match($regex, "The cat likes her mat", $m);
```

I have this result:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'cat likes her mat' (length=17)
  1 => string 'cat' (length=3)
  2 => string ' likes her ' (length=11)
  3 => string 'mat' (length=3)
```

I voted for Casimir's result, however his pattern returns false positive on these strings:

```
cat likesher mat
cat likes  her mat
cat mat
```

Comment: Thank you. In my actual usage, all the 'words' are fixed length and always separated by a space. So Casimir's pattern works what I need. But your answer is probably the better solution to the question as I posed it.

Comment: I'm glad to help you both. Just watch the case if you have words *motor*, *cycle*, but NOT *motorcycle*